# CSS do Blueimp Gallery não funciona com Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Veja o código a seguir:

```js
document.getElementById('links').onclick = function(event) {
  event = event || window.event;
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
    link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
    options = {
      index: link,
      event: event
    },
    links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
  blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
};
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-gallery/2.33.0/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-gallery/2.33.0/js/blueimp-helper.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-gallery/2.33.0/js/blueimp-gallery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-gallery/2.33.0/js/blueimp-gallery-fullscreen.js"></script>


<!-- The Gallery as lightbox dialog, should be a child element of the document body -->
<div id="blueimp-gallery" class="blueimp-gallery blueimp-gallery-controls">
  <div class="slides"></div>
  <h3 class="title"></h3>
  <a class="prev">‹</a>
  <a class="next">›</a>
  <a class="close">×</a>
  <a class="play-pause"></a>
  <ol class="indicator"></ol>
</div>

<div id="links">
  <a href="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" title="Avião">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/airplane.png" alt="Avião" width="50">
    </a>
  <a href="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png" title="Pool">
        <img src="https://homepages.cae.wisc.edu/~ece533/images/pool.png" alt="Pool" width="50">
    </a>
</div>
```

O [resultado](https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/) que eu espero é assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pode ver que a imagem acima, o botão (próximo, anterior e fechar) está com a cor branca ao posicionar em cima. Já o meu código fica dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que estou fazendo de errado ? Alguma solução ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é que o reebot do Bootstrap está fazendo aplicando esse CSS. Repare que ali o `color` está como `inherit`. Porém dessa forma ele herda a cor "errada" herdada do `body`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o CSS do `reebot.scss` que está aplicando a cor errada no elemento com `color: inherit;`. Veja que essa classe tem um força grande e é complicada sobrescreve-la sem ter que usar um `!important` ou um `#id`, então o ideal e replica-la no CSS *override* de CSS e colocar a cor que vc queira.

```
a:not([href]):not([tabindex]) {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):focus, 
a:not([href]):not([tabindex]):hover {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Um *workaround* seria vc fazer um *override* dessa classe no seu `custom.css` ou algum outro CSS que vc está chamando ai depois do `bootstrap.css` e ai colocar a cor que vc deseja.